# Public Static List Method

Tags: soql, list, method, static

I have been studying Salesforce Dev for the past few weeks and can't find any documentation on something very simple. Can anyone explain why I would make the public static method a type of list rather then just having the list inside of the method? Why wouldn't I simply have the list inside of a non-list method and then when I call 'return', the method will return a list.

```
public class ContactAndLeadSearch {
    public static List<List<SObject>> searchContactsAndLeads(String a) {
        list<list<sObject>> stringy = [find :a IN ALL FIELDS Returning lead(FirstName, LastName), contact(firstname, lastname)];
    return stringy;    
    }
}
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Here are the components of that method declaration:

1. Access Modifier - `public`
2. Static vs. Instance - `static`
3. Return Type - `List<List<SObject>>`
4. Method Name - `searchContactsAndLeads`
5. Parameters - `String a`

---

1. You would mark this method `public` if you intend for it to be accessible from another `Apex Class` or `Apex Trigger`. **See [Access Modifiers](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_access_modifiers.htm)**.

---

2. You would mark this method `static` because you can easily pass its entire state (just one `String` variable) in via method parameters. **See [Static and Instance Methods, Variables, and Initialization Code](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_static.htm)**.

---

3. Your return type is `List<List<SObject>>` because that is what `SOSL` itself returns. Your posted query would return a `List<List<SObject>>` containing one `List<Lead>` and one `List<Contact>`. **You must specify a return type when defining methods, otherwise the compiler will interpret them as a constructor.**

---

4. The method name is probably overly verbose. The class name too. If I were writing this class, I might name it `ContactsAndLeads`, then just name the method itself `search`.

---

5. The parameter your method accepts is of the type `String`. It could probably also be renamed to be more informative, perhaps to `searchTerm`.

Comment: Sorry, I still don't quite understand. I must be missing some core concepts. I understood that List<List<SObject>> was needed because I am making a list of leads and a list of contacts. So two lists there for my SOQL query. I still don't understand why I would need the:  

public static List<List<SObject>>....

It just seems redundant to me. Why can't it be:

public class ContactAndLeadSearch {
    public static searchContactsAndLeads(String a) {
        list<list<sObject>> stringy = [find :a IN ALL FIELDS Returning lead(FirstName, LastName), contact(firstname, lastname)];

Comment: idea is that signature of the method should contain type that is being returned in Apex

Comment: If you do not define a return type, the compiler interprets your method as a constructor.

Comment: Thank you for the break down! I understand now. The constructor part was what I was missing.